# Diversity VIsa Interview-Police Certificate

Tags: usa, visa, immigration

My interview is next week and my husband is the principal applicant. I am currently not living in my country of citizenship.
When KCC asked for the documents, I sent PCC just for my current country of residence and they never asked for more. However, now that i am reading forums to prepare for the interview, I see that i am suppoed to take a PCC from my country of nationality as well. Is it absolutely necessary? The process is quite long and for sure it wont be ready before the interview. What can I do?

Comment: What are KCC and PCC?

Comment: KCC- Kentucky Consular Centre; PCC- Police Clearance Certificate